# Get item by title and path using core service

Tags: core-service

I want to get the item(Page,CT,PT) by its title and path.Since there may be  more than one item matching the search criteria if we search only by title so I want to search the item by its name and path.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the core service supports both regular tcm id's and webdav urls when reading from the CM.
So, instead of

```
client.Read("tcm:1-123", new ReadOptions())
```

you can also do something like

```
client.Read("/webdav/publication%20name/folder%20names/component%20name.xml", new ReadOptions())
```

Do note that the webdav path should be url encoded (spaces, accents,...)
Also don't forget that tridion items have specific extensions (component has .xml, page has .tpg, page template has .tptcmp and component template has .tctcmp)

Comment: @Haraid is the webdav path is case sensitive?